# Pandas Style Bar converts my data into 6 decimals

Tags: python, pandas

when using pd.Style.Bar, pandas converts my data to 6 decimals. Can anybody help me ?

Example :

```
import pandas as pd
data = [[0.02, 0.04],[0.06, 0.07]]
dt = pd.DataFrame(data)

a = dt.style.bar(align = 'mid', color = ['lightblue', 'red'])
```

or even trying :

```
a = (dt.style.bar(align = 'mid', color = ['lightblue', 'red'])
     .applymap('{:,.2f}'.format))
```

Both give me the following output (with the column bars - sorry I can't copy here) :

```
             0           1
0     0.020000    0.040000
1     0.060000    0.070000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to ensure that the precision of `a` is `2`, you could call [`pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.set_precision`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.set_precision.html) when defining `a`.

**Example**

```py
import pandas as pd

data = [[0.02, 0.04],[0.06, 0.07]]
dt = pd.DataFrame(data)
a = dt.style.bar(align = 'mid', color = ['lightblue', 'red']).set_precision(2)
```

**`a`**

```
       0       1
0   0.02    0.04
1   0.06    0.07
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [[0.02, 0.04],[0.06, 0.07]]
dt = pd.DataFrame(data)
a = dt.style.bar(align = 'mid', color = ['lightblue', 'red']).format('{0:,.2f}')
```

Comment: @jorge: Great, it's my pleasure!